# TypeError jQuery offset().top is undefined

Tags: jquery, css, offset, typeerror

The Firefox debugger is showing a TypeError for a jQuery function aimed at sticking a navbar to the to the top of the page when a user scrolls and updating the class at the same time.

The function is below.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top>30) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("sticky");
    }
    else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

The resulting error is this.

> Timestamp: 31/01/2014 10:01:04
>
> Error: TypeError: `$(...).offset(...)` is undefined

I have looked about on SO for a similar example but can not translate the outcomes into a fix.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it the element your are getting the offset displayed?

Comment: Where is the relevant HTML markup?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It 's because your $(".navbar") cannot be found. Check if the element exist before getting offset.

```
if ($(".navbar").length) {...}
```

Comment: Or if the object is not visible also it return undefined

Comment: Try using an ID instead.

Answer (score 2):

it work for me like this

```
$('.custom-scrollbar').animate({
    scrollTop: $('a.sidebar-link.sidebar-title.active').offset.top - 200
}, 1000);
```

offset without ()