# Sticky navbar using Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi all I am trying to make the navbar that will stick to the page just after my header but when I make it fixed using the following code
`<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">`

but when I do that the navbar overfloats the header and it doesnt work as it should.

**HTML**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <p>"Blabla"</p>
    <h1>blasa</h1>
    <p>Ssasasasdsad sadsaas</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">sadsadasd</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">hgfgfsf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dsasafew</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dsadsaf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dsadasd</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cdas</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
      jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
    } else {
      jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixrd");
    }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .sidenav {
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .row.content {
    height: auto;
  }
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

I would be greatful if you could help me :)

Thanks

Comment: Any chance you could get a fiddle up with your CSS and JS, so we can get a better idea of the issue?

Comment: Remove the `navbar-fixed-top` and try with the [Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix).

Comment: just updated the question, hope that will help to find the issue. Thanks :) ps. this is my first website that I creating using bootstrap and 4 ever created site :)

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Comment: Future readers see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933630/bootstrap-4-sticky-top-class-on-navbar-not-working/51933889#51933889

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things here.  First you don't need to wrap your nav in the `<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">` because you are stating the navbar stylings in the nav so you can remove that div completely and just use `<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">`.  The reason why is for one the navbar-fixed-top is bootstraps style for having a fixed nav at the top of your page at all times and you don't want it to be fixed until you scroll to it and the navbar-default class is a style for the navbar and you are using navbar-inverse inside of it which is negating the default style anyway, so just remove the div wrapping your nav and you should be fine there.

Next you have a typo in your removeClass selector of your jquery code it says fixrd instead of fixed.

Then in your css you will want to add a left:0; to your `.fixed` class and a width of 100%.

Then I would assume that you don't want the space between the nav and the jumbotron so if you don't then you may want to give the jumbotron a margin-bottom of zero.

Here is a fiddle demo to show you it working [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/hdjz4yt6/)

After these minor changes you should be good to go it should look like this:

Html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <p>"Blabla"</p>
    <h1>blasa</h1>
    <p>Ssasasasdsad sadsaas</p>
  </div>
</div>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">sadsadasd</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">hgfgfsf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dsasafew</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dsadsaf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dsadasd</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cdas</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Css:

```
.fixed{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;left:0;
  width:100%;
}
.jumbotron{
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

And Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
      jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
    } else {
      jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477560/typeerror-jquery-offset-top-is-undefined

Answer (score -1):

You can use Bootstrap 3s [Affix](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) Plugin for this. You shouldn't need to use to separate navbars for this and you have you're closing navbar divs out of order (which i edited for you):

What you had:

```
  <div/>
<nav/>
```

Should be:

```
  <nav/>
<div/>
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$('.navbar').affix({
  offset: {
    top: function() {
      return (this.top = $('.navbar').offset().top)
    }
  }
});
```

```css
header.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-default.affix {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <p>"Blabla"</p>
    <h1>blasa</h1>
    <p>Ssasasasdsad sadsaas</p>
  </div>
</header>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">sadsadasd</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">hgfgfsf</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">dsasafew</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">dsadsaf</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">dsadasd</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cdas</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container text-center">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
    galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
    containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Updated Answer**

You have a few errors: `<script src=java.js "></script>` your file needs to have a quote at the start: `<script src="java.js"></script>` and icon link in the head is a problem as well (I'm not sure what the link is to so other then removing and starting over I can say).

Your CSS is missing some closing brackets:
The **media query** itself isn't closed along with the first rule, `.carousel-caption`.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .carousel-caption {
        display: none;
    }
    .navbar {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    .row.content {
        height: 450px
    }
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 20px;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

**Updated Working Example:**

```js
$('.navbar').affix({
  offset: {
    top: function() {
      return (this.top = $('.navbar').offset().top)
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .carousel-caption {
    display: none;
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */
  }
  .navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
  .row.content {
    height: 450px
  }
  /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
/* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .sidenav {
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .row.content {
    height: auto;
  }
}
/* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .sidenav {
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .row.content {
    height: auto;
  }
}
.panel-footer.panel-custom {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.navbar.navbar-default.affix {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
header.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<header class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <p>"dfds"</p>
    <h1>fds</h1>
    <p>fdsfdsfsdfdsfsd</p>
  </div>
</header>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">sadsadasd</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">hgfgfsf</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">dsasafew</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">dsadsaf</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">dsadasd</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cdas</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400?text=IMAGE" alt="Image">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Sell $</h3>
              <p>Money Money.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400?text=Another Image Maybe" alt="Image">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>More Sell $</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400?text=Another Image Maybe" alt="Image">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>More Sell $</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <p>info</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <p>info</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <p>info</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <p>info</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <p>info</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>

<div class="container text-center">
  <h3>What We Do</h3>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
      <p>Current Project</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
      <p>Project 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="well">
        <p>info</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>info</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="well">
        <p>info</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>info</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>

<div class="container text-center">
  <h3>Our Partners</h3>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
      <p>Partner 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
      <p>Partner 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
      <p>Partner 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
      <p>Partner 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
      <p>Partner 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
      <p>Partner 6</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"><center>Collapsible Group 1</center></a>
            </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <center>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2"><center>Collapsible Group 2</center></a>
            </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <center>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3"><center>Collapsible Group 3</center></a>
            </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <center>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thnaks, however I still cant make it work , I just manage to apply the design aspect to the page, the sticky part will not work :(

Comment: Do you have all of the dependencies like jquery and bootstrap js in your project?

Comment: do you mean all of the scripts? 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: Yes. And without more information its hard to say what the issue is.

Comment: I just uploaded my code, I hope this will help. p.s. I appropriate your help and time. I am really grateful.

Comment: See the updated answer and you should move the code you posted up into your original question.