# How to place navbar below sticky navbar using bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am using bootstrap 4 to make an application, in which i have two navbars and both needs to be fixed at top in which the second navbar needs to hide while scrolling.

Html:

**Navbar 1:**

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-custom-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row w-100">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    New Project
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 d-none d-sm-none d-md-block mt-2">
                <h4 class="font-weight-600">
                    Little description
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3"></div>
            <div class="col-3 mt-3 d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">
                <ul class="navbar-nav pl-5">
                    <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            Notification
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item font-weight-600 mr-3">
                        <a class="nav-link text-capitalize" href="#">
                            Hello Admin
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item font-weight-600 mr-3">
                        <a class="nav-link text-capitalize mr-3" href="#">
                            Profile
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                search
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Navbar 2:**

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li> 
    </ul>
  </div> 
</nav>
```

Here both the navbar needs to be fixed top for which i have used `fixed-top` class..

But as of now the navbars are overlapping each other.

You could see in the link https://www.bootply.com/y8EfMpCMc4# where the overlapping happens.

Kindly help me to place a navbar 2 below navbar 1 with position fixed (which also needs to be responsive), in which the navbar 2 alone needs to be in collapsed for small devices and needs to be on right side of navbar 1's navbrand ie.right to `New Project`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sticky-top` on the 1st instead of `fixed-top`, and make the 2nd navbar static by removing `fixed-top`.

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-custom-light"></nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark"></nav>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/vbF0Sch9xc

---

Related:
[Bootstrap 4 collapsing two navbars into one toggle button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970058/bootstrap-4-collapsing-two-navbars-into-one-toggle-button)
[Bootstrap 4 Multiple fixed-top navbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417018/bootstrap-4-multiple-fixed-top-navbars)